# Index nodes and measure Query execution time in Neo4j

Tags: database, neo4j, graph-databases, sql-execution-plan

The dataset contains various IDs with each ID having many events at different timestamps and Performer.

For example

```
ID, DateStamp, Assignment_Group
ID1, 10:00:00, Group1
ID1, 11:14:36, Group2
ID2, 11:23:34, Group2
ID3, 1:34,23, Group3
```

.....

I have created the nodes for each attributes and linked them via relations as

```
try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx();) {
    myNode1[i] = db.createNode();
    myNode1[i].setProperty("ID", input_data[0]);
    myNode2[i] = db.createNode();
    myNode2[i].setProperty("DateStamp", input_data[1]);
    relation1=myNode1[i].createRelationshipTo(myNode2[i], OCCURS_AT);
    relation1.setProperty("occuredAt", "some time");
    myNode3[i] = db.createNode();
    myNode3[i].setProperty("Assignment_Group", input_data[2]);
    relation2=myNode1[i].createRelationshipTo(myNode3[i], RESOLVED_BY);
    relation2.setProperty("ResolvedBy", "some group");
    tx.success();
}
```

I would like to index the record on the basis of myNode1[]. Would like to know if the same is possible and how?

Also is it possible to measure query execution time? The current approach doesn't seem good

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
result = engine.execute("match (n {Incident_ID: 'ID1'}) return n.Incident_ID");
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time + "ms");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily index your nodes. You can either give your different types of nodes labels and use schema indexing (neo4j 2.0 and up) or use legacy indexing. This is all described in the Neo4j Manual, chapters [13](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-schema.html), [19](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-indexes.html), and [34](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing.html).

Beyond this, do you really need to make nodes for your date stamps? Consider putting the DateStamp property on the OCCURS_AT relationships.

Comment: Thank You. @Jim Biard. And what is the correct way for measuring the query execution time?